# jsrsasign library - How to generate HMAC-SHA256?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, sha256, hmac, microsoft-teams

I am trying to validate a Microsoft Teams outgoing webhook message to my Rest endpoint. In the header "authorization" HTTP Post request from Teams, there is a HMAC signature that I need to verify, per their documentation I need to:

1. Generate the hmac from the request body of the message. There are standard libraries to do this on most platforms. Microsoft Teams uses standard SHA256 HMAC cryptography. You will need to convert the body to a byte array in UTF8.
2. To compute the hash, provide the byte array of the security token provided by Microsoft Teams when you registered the outgoing webhook.
3. Convert the hash to a string using UTF8 encoding.
4. Compare the string value of the generated hash with the value provided in the HTTP request.

---

My REST endpoint is ServiceNow and it is limited when it comes to native JS function. I was able to successfully imported the jsrsasign library and confirmed it work correctly with validating the JWT before. I looked at their API documentation on MAC and Message Digest but did not quite get what I needed to do. Could any one help me with examples on how to use this library to generate HMAC signature so I can compare with the HMAC i received?
I tried something like this but did not seem to work:

---

```
var HMAC = request.getHeader('authorization');
var secret = gs.base64Decode('rZ84WrEZ');
var body = JSON.stringify(request.body.data);

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encode(body), encode(secret)));
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

//Read online that JS string is stored as utf-16, so i use the function below to turn it into utf-8

function encode (string) {

    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");

    var utftext = "";


    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {


        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);


        if (c < 128) {

            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);

        }

        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {

            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);

            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);

        }

        else {

            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);

            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);

            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);

        }


    }
    return utftext;
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the other side? If so, follow step, if not convert base64 and str compare.

Comment: I did not implement the other side. What do i need to convert to base64?  The message(request body)?  Or the variable macHex?

Comment: macHex that needs to compare. Make sure that you are using the same steps.

Comment: doesnt seem to work correctly. im not sure if i need to do anything to the body message or the secret key before passing them in as parameter.

Comment: did you self checked? calculate the hmac two times and compare them and see that it is working?  Also check the hmac value by online hmacs

Comment: There are so many different things I see online that just confuse me. some hash converter online expect input to be in utf8, some strings. Then I tried to hash both the message and the secret key and then use an online HMAC generator to generate HMAC, this value is then converted to base64 which does not match and longer than the HMAC i received: FwoNdnBPXpLmGapSlqSXzHWlotY0W1HpDzGI8F7wbCc= (i tried to convert this to base64 as well but no luck). Have you used jsrsasign lib before to verify the hmac value? Sorry for all these questions as I am brand new to all this HMAC stuff

Comment: base64 is longer, [6 bit](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiU3tLL0v7dAhXPZ1AKHaHEC2cQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcrypto.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F50308%2Fwhat-are-usual-base64-encryption-strategies&psig=AOvVaw0F1WWqUiKa3Nb8BSz-NBIa&ust=1539356127448347) opposed to 8 bit asscii. Your problem is encoding.

Comment: I tried to encode it into utf-8, is that what you meant? please see me updated question with the code.